# Jetpack Compose : Scrollable column with fractions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have 3 elements in a column.

I want the 1st element to take 50% of screen and the remaining to take rest of space or scroll if needed.

I have tried the following:

- Using verticallScroll() with fractions is not working. If i disable verticallScroll() then the 1st element takes 50% of the screen but the screen does not scrolls if needed.

  ```
   Column(
       modifier = Modifier
           .background(color = Color.Black)
           .padding(horizontal = 15.dp)
           .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState(), enabled = true)
           .fillMaxSize()

   ) {
       QuickTipsCard(
           modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth()
               .fillMaxHeight(0.5f),
           backgroundColor = LightBlue,
           title = "Good morning!",
           description = "0 out of 10 task today",
           titleStyle = Typography.h1
       )
  ```

  }

Comment: Should the 1st element scroll?

Comment: Yes. It should scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `Column` in a `BoxWithConstraints` component and use the maxHeight property to calculate the desired heights for the elements in the column.